# What is the source of the smoke smell around Nuevo/Puerto Vallarta?

Tags: air-quality, puerto-vallarta

I'm currently in Nuevo Vallarta by the beach, close to PVR airport and there's a persistent smell of smoke in the mornings. I can't find any reports of [forest fires](https://www.google.com/search?q=mexico+forest+fire) in the area so I'm struggling to figure out the source.

The purpose of the question is to figure out whether there's a super-localized problem with smoke in Nuevo Vallarta (say, from burning trash nearby) or whether it's a persistent problem across the entire region. I have a sensitive sense of smell so I always try to choose destinations that have clean air.

Comment: How cold is it at night? Perhaps people have wood stoves for heat, and the cool air keeps the smoke down near the ground until the sun comes up.

Comment: @JonCuster I've seen stats that suggest 25% of Mexican homes use wood stoves.  Also the current weather in Puerto Vallarta has PM2.5 particulate pollution on the cusp between Good and Moderate air pollution (but trending down significantly over the next week - so perhaps a temperature inversion?)

Comment: @PeterM - and burning piñon or juniper makes for very noticeable wood smoke. All it takes is one person in my neighborhood and I can smell it.

Comment: @JonCuster Although I also live in a area with a high number of wood stoves (and know what burning piñon and juniper smells like), I'm curious as to why the Puerto Vallarta [Air Quality Index](https://www.iqair.com/us/mexico/jalisco/puerto-vallarta) is trending down over the coming week, given that the the wind direction and strength are essentially stable during that time.

Comment: @JonCuster it’s 17C at night so I strongly doubt anyone’s burning wood for heating. I sleep with an open window and no AC.

Comment: @JonathanReez - yet the valley is surrounded by hills that are 500m and more higher, so it is cooler up there and the smoke will drop into the valley.

Comment: Also the locals may have a different view of the temperature. As an example, at work we currently have some folks coming in from Las Vegas. They wear puffy down jackets and we wear maybe a sweatshirt in 0-10C…

Comment: @JonathanReez Wood stoves may also be used for other than heating .. like, you know .. cooking.

Comment: And uninsulated cement block houses are freezing. Possibly dirt floors too

Comment: @JonCuster its plausible, I'm just trying to see whether Puerto Vallarta as a whole is a no-go for me in the future or whether I'm just unlucky this week or whether its just Nuevo Vallarta that's a problem.

Comment: @JonathanReez an internet search found several threads (dating at least back to 2011) complaining about smoke in Nuevo/Puerto Vallarta (burning fields, palm leaves, etc.).

Comment: @mkennedy That sounds like an actual answer

Comment: @PeterM Maybe? It's all people venting on tripadvisor with mostly speculation as to causes.

Comment: It is slash and burn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash-and-burn